# MIPS Programming instruction count issue

Tags: mips

I wrote this mips code to find the gcf but I am confused on getting the number of instructions executed for this code. I need to find a linear function as a function of number of times the remainder must be calculated before an answer. i tried running this code using Single step with Qtspim but not sure on how to proceed.

```
gcf:
    addiu   $sp,$sp,-4              # adjust the stack for an item
    sw      $ra,0($sp)              # save return address

    rem     $t4,$a0,$a1             # r = a % b
    beq     $t4,$zero,L1            # if(r==0) go to L1
    add     $a0,$zero,$a1           # a = b
    add     $a1,$zero,$t4           # b = r
    jr      gcf

L1:
    add     $v0,$zero,$a1           # return b
    addiu   $sp,$sp,4               # pop 2 items
    jr      $ra                     # return to caller
```

Comment: The first problem was to actually write this code. I wrote this code to find gcf and it works but con't figure out what they want me to do to find the instructions. I tried running this code step by step but i am not sure how to get the linear function. Is there any formula or method to solve it?

Comment: Done. Does it make sense now? I just wanna know of a method to do so.

Comment: Looks a lot better.

Comment: The `jr gcf` is invalid. `jr` is "jump _register_" and `gcf` is a label. Did you mean `j gcf`? That wouldn't work because you'd loop back and create a huge number of stack frames.

Comment: Yes. You were right. I just fixed that. Also, do you know if there is any formula to get a linear function for number of instructions? Thank you so much for your response.

Comment: I tried counting the number of instructions but I can't account for all the cases that way.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing new to show here, the algorithm you just implemented is the Euclidean algorithm and it is well known in the literature<sup>1</sup>.

I will nonetheless write an informal analysis here as link only questions are evil.

---

First lets rewrite the code in an high level formulation:

```
unsigned int gcd(unsigned  int a, unsigned int b)
{
   if (a % b == 0)
      return b;

   return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```

<sup><sub>The choice of `unsigned int` vs `int` was dicated by the MIPS ISA that makes `rem` undefined for negative operands.</sub></sup>

Out goal is to find a function *T(a, b)* that gives the number of step the algorithm requires to compute the GDC of *a* and *b*.

Since a direct approach leads to nothing, we try by inverting the problem.
What pairs *(a, b)* makes *T(a, b) = 1*, in other words what pairs make *gcd(a, b)* terminates in one step?
We clearly must have that *a % b = 0*, which means that *a* must be a multiple of *b*.
There are actually an (countable) infinite number of pairs, we can limit our selves to pairs with the smallest, *a* and *b*<sup>2</sup>.

To recap, to have *T(a, b) = 1* we need *a = nb* and we pick the pair *(a, b) = (1, 1)*.

Now, given a pair *(c, d)* that requires *N* steps, how do we find a new pair *(a, b)* such that *T(a, b) = T(c, d) + 1*?

Since *gcd(a, b)* must take one step further then *gcd(c, d)* and since starting from *gcd(a, b)* the next step is *gcd(b, a % b)* we must have:

```
c = b     => b = c
d = a % b => d = a % c => a = c + d
```

The step `d = a % c => a = c + d` comes from the minimality of *a*, we need the smallest *a* that when divided by *c* gives *d*, so we can take *a = c + d* since *(c + d) % c = c % c d % c = 0 + d = d*.

For *d % c = d* to be true we need that *d < c*.
Our base pair was *(1, 1)* which doesn't satisfy this hypothesis, luckily we can take *(2, 1)* as the base pair (convince your self that *T(2, 1) = 1*).

Then we have:

```
gcd(3, 2) = gcd(2, 1) = 1
T(3, 2) = 1 + T(2, 1) = 1 + 1 = 2

gcd(5, 3) = gcd(3, 2) = 1
T(5, 3) = 1 + T(3, 2) = 1 + 2 = 3

gcd(8, 5) = gcd(5, 3) = 1
T(8, 5) = 1 + T(5, 3) = 1 + 3 = 4

...
```

If we look at the pair *(2, 1)*, *(3, 2)*, *(5, 3)*, *(8, 5)*, ... we see that the n-th pair (starting from 1) is made by the number *(F<sub>n+1</sub>, F<sub>n</sub>)*.
Where *F<sub>n</sub>* is the n-th Fibonacci number.

We than have:

*T(F<sub>n+1</sub>, F<sub>n</sub>)* = n

Regarding Fibonacci number we know that *F<sub>n</sub> ∝ φ<sup>n</sup>*.

We are now going to use all the trickery of asymptotic analysis, particularly in the limit of the big-O notation considering *φ<sup>n</sup>* or *φ<sup>n + 1</sup>* is the same.
Also we won't use the big-O symbol explicitly, we rather assume that each equality is true in the limit. This is an abuse, but makes the analysis more compact.

We can assume without loss of generality that *N* is an upper bound for both number in the pair and that it is proportional to *φ<sup>n</sup>*.
We have *N ∝ φ<sup>n</sup>* that gives *log<sub>φ</sub> N = n*, this ca be rewritten as *log(N)/log(φ) = n* (where logs are in base 10 and *log(φ)* can be taken to be 1/5).
Thus we finally have *5logN = n* or written in reverse order

*n = 5 logN*

Where *n* is the number of step taken by *gcd(a, b)* where *0 < b < a < N*.

---

We can further show that if *a = ng* and *b = mg* with *n*, *m* coprimes, than *T(a, b) = T(n, m)* thus the restriction of taking the minimal pairs is not bounding.

---

<sup>1</sup> In the eventuality that you rediscovered such algorithm, I strongly advice against continue with reading this answer. You surely have a sharp mind that would benefit the most from a challenge than from an answer.
<sup>2</sup> We'll later see that this won't give rise to a loss of generality.